# java UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Trying to figure out how to run my project at the moment. Java is complaining of:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to load the native library: lwjgl."
```

I am trying to use this to execute the code:

```
java -Djava.library.path="lib\native\windows\x64\lwjgl.dll" -cp bin;lib\* Space
```

Directories for the project are as follows:

```
├───bin
├───lib
│   └───native
│       ├───linux
│       │   ├───x64
│       │   └───x86
│       ├───macosx
│       │   └───x64
│       └───windows
│           ├───x64
│           └───x86
└───src
```

Comment: Isn't "lib\native\wi..." a relative path name? Same in -cp bin;lib\*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with:

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib\native\windows\x64\ -cp bin;lib\*; Space
```

Apparently there shouldn't be quotations around the path, and it should point to a directory not a file.